# Why is SqlTransaction zombified

Tags: .net, sql-server, .net-core

I have a `SqlTransaction` that performs some operations, first deleting data, then inserting with `SqlBulkCopy`. Sometimes happens that the `SqlTransaction` has `Connection` set to null after some time in processing and an attempt to insert more rows with `SqlBulkCopy` results in error:

> The transaction is either not associated with the current connection
> or has been completed

When I looked into source code, there is an internal state when the transaction is zombified, and my transaction probably got into this state.

Is there some way to find out why the transaction got into this state?

The exception:

> **The transaction is either not associated with the current connection
> or has been completed.**    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CreateOrValidateConnection(String
> method)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteRowSourceToServerAsync(Int32
> columnCount, CancellationToken ctoken)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(DataRow[] rows,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: Are you doing stuff in parallel? (It's impossible to help you just with a description of the problem without any code)

Comment: @gsharp Yes, there are other transactions on that table from other processes.

Comment: Then I would start looking there. "sometimes happens" sounds like a thread is sometimes faster than the other and messes up your connection/transaction.

Comment: Are you always using a single connection and transaction on each thread? The connection and transaction objects are not multi-threaded, and should be disposed immediately after use with a `using` block. Please [edit] and add relevant code

Comment: @Charlieface I tried to turn on logging info messages on the SqlConnection, it turned out there was a deadlock. It is strange the deadlock did not cause and exception, though.

Comment: 1. That should not by itself cause a zombied transaction, you should still be able to back out and rollback, so somehow the connection is being dropped with the transaction still open. As I said, you need to have proper `using` blocks 2. I suggest you create a new question containing the relevant SQL query, table and index definitions, the deadlock graph (you can get this from SQL Profiler) and share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: It’s when you continue using the transaction after having run transaction.Rollback(). Your code must exit after first error and rollback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to **turn on logging info messages** on the SqlConnection:

```
CurrentConnection = new SqlConnection(theConnectionString);
CurrentConnection.Open();
CurrentConnection.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;
CurrentConnection.InfoMessage += CurrentConnection_InfoMessage;


private void CurrentConnection_InfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
{
    var errors = new List<string>();
    if (e.Errors != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Errors.Count; i++)
        {
            errors.Add(e.Errors[i].ToString());
        }
    }

    _logger.LogEvent($"SQL connection info message: source={e.Source}, message={e.Message}, errors={string.Join(',', errors)}");
}
```

It turned out there was a **deadlock**:

> SQL connection info message: source=Core .Net SqlClient Data Provider,
> message=Transaction (Process ID 134) was deadlocked on lock |
> communication buffer resources with another process and has been
> chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.